# Regression Model to obtain ATET

Tags: regression, linear-model, treatment-effect, control-group

I'm working on a problem where I have two groups that both received a different treatment and one controlgroup. The total number of people in this experiment is 10,000 and the participants where randomly selected in each group.

I'm trying to obtain the ATET for both groups that received the treatment. How would a regression model for this problem look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding that you have three groups total, treatment A, treatment B, and control. You're interested in the effect of treatment A vs. control and the effect of treatment B vs. control. You mentioned you wanted the ATET (average treatment effect on the treated); because you randomly assigned participants, each treated group has the same distribution of covariates as each of the other groups and of the whole sample, so the ATET is equal to the ATE (average treatment effect). The ATET and ATE only differ in observational studies, not randomized experiments.

A regression model would involve creating two dummy (0/1) variables, $d_A$ and $d_B$, one for each treatment level (not control). For each treatment level, the corresponding dummy variable is 1 when the participant is in that treatment group and 0 otherwise. Participants in the control group will receive a 0 on both variables. You then fit the following regression model:
$$
E[y_i]=\beta_0 + \beta_1 d_{Ai} + \beta_2 d_{Bi}
$$
The coefficients $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ represent the differences between the mean in the control group and the means in treatment A and treatment B, respectively. That is, $\beta_1$ is the effect of treatment A vs. control, and $\beta_2$ is the effect of treatment B vs. control.